# Multiple Docker Hub builds by parameterization

Tags: docker, dockerhub, auto-build

I have a requirement to build the same Dockerfile on a (relatively large) number of flavours.

In particular, I am working on a customization of Apache Tomcat. With the same Dockerfile, applying some enhancements to base Tomcat, I need to build several customized Tomcats based on different versions (n particular at least the baselines `8.5` and `9` combined with JDKs `8` and `11`).

**As an exercise only**, just o get more practice on Docker, I could even decide to build all Tomcat images, which come in a large number of flavours, as customized builds.

Given that I already have a Dockerfile...

```
ARG TOMCAT_VERSION
FROM tomcat:${TOMCAT_VERSION}
MAINTAINER Some One (someone@example.biz)
ARG POSTGRES_JDBC_VERSION="42.2.16"
ARG ORACLE_JDBC_VERSION="19.7.0.0"
ARG LIFECYCLE_LISTENER_VERSION="1.0.1"
ENV MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 4096
ARG CONTEXT_NAME

ADD https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/aschemann/tomcat/tomcat-lifecyclelistener/${LIFECYCLE_LISTENER_VERSION}/tomcat-lifecyclelistener-${LIFECYCLE_LISTENER_VERSION}.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib
ADD https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/postgresql/postgresql/${POSTGRES_JDBC_VERSION}/postgresql-${POSTGRES_JDBC_VERSION}.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib
ADD https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/${ORACLE_JDBC_VERSION}/ojdbc8-${ORACLE_JDBC_VERSION}.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib
COPY tomcat-${TOMCAT_MAJOR}/server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/ #This enables AJP

EXPOSE 8009
EXPOSE 8080

VOLUME #some volume
# etc etc
```

What I need to achieve is, possibly using Docker Hub's auto-build is

```
for (tomcatVersion in "8.5", "9")
    for (javaVersion in "jd8-slim", "jdk11-slim", "jdk14")
        docker build --build-arg TOMCAT_VERSION=$tomcatVersion+"-"+$javaVersion -t examplebiz/tomcat:$tomcatVersion+"-"+$javaVersion .
```

Currently Docker Hub offers to me use multiple Github branches

[image: Docker Hub Build Settings]

But I don't like this, as a single Dockerfile is sufficient. I can combine the 6 versions and run the build manually from my pc

I haven't very well understood the build hooks. Maybe there lies the solution?

Can I get some advice on how to design the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to BMitch's answer, I also found my own way in the meantime and I'd like to share my experience, possibly explaining.

Docker Hub allows hooks automation. In particular, the `build` hook, as described in [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/#build-hook-examples), will override the entire build process. One can choose whether to change the variables passed to Docker, or to reinvent brand new ways of building!!

I just had to translate my pseudo-code for cycle into a real bash for cycle

```
#!/bin/bash

for tomcatVersion in "8.5" "9" ; do
    for javaVersion in "jdk8-slim" "jdk11-slim" "jdk14" ; do
        imageVersion="$tomcatVersion-$javaVersion"
        echo "Building Tomcat $imageVersion"
        docker build --build-arg TOMCAT_VERSION=$imageVersion -t examplebiz/tomcat:$imageVersion .;
        docker push examplebiz/tomcat:$imageVersion
    done
done

docker tag examplebiz/tomcat:$imageVersion examplebiz/tomcat:latest
```

There are just two caveats:

1. Docker Hub won't ever push anything by itself. Whatever custom you build, you must push it. That is why I have the docker push line and I use the last value of the variable `imageVersion` in my code
2. Docker Hub will push a `repository:latest` image after the build, so it demands its presence. Make your choice on who to promote latest, but make sure Docker has built a `latest` image, whether with a tag or a plain build

Answer (score 1):

The functionality from Docker Hub builds doesn't have a lot of options. If you need more configurability and are hosting your project in GitHub, have a look at GitHub Actions instead.

Docker has a [build-push](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) action that has lots of options. And to support the multiple options, the [matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategy) syntax in GitHub actions allows you to run multiple builds with different settings. What you're left with looks like a file call `.github/workflows/docker.yml` in your project (`docker` can be renamed) with:

```
name: docker

on:
  push:
    branches: master

jobs:
  docker:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        tomcatVer: ["8.5", "9"]
        javaVer: ["jd8-slim", "jdk11-slim", "jdk14"]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1 
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: examplebiz/tomcat:${{ matrix.tomcatVer }}-${{ matrix.javaVer }}
          build-args: |
            TOMCAT_VERSION=${{ matrix.tomcatVer }}-${{ matrix.javaVer }}
```